# How can I get a div to take up the whole bottom of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I have three divs arranged horizontally, and I'd like for the bottom div to just take up the bottom of the screen. As it is, the bottom most div doesn't do that-there's whitespace at the bottom. How do I get it so that only the three divs are showing?

```html
<div id="the whole thing" style="height:100%; width:100%">

  <div id="toprow" style="position: relative; width:100%; height:150px; background-color:red;color:white">
    First row
  </div>

  <div id="secondrow" style="position: relative; width:100%; height: 300px;background-color:black;color:white">
    Second row
  </div>

  <div id="thirdrow" style="position: relative; width:100%; height:100%;background-color:blue;color:white">
    Third row
  </div>


</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest flex for this. Here you'll find a good documentation: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: `display: flex`  + `min-height: 100vh` to the container and then make use of `flex-grow` for at least one child element.

Comment: That actually worked when I added the min-height to the other answer that used flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the best solution but it works here and as suggested to you it's better to use flexbox

I only change the height to 100vh which to take the full height of the web page but 100% will not take the full page as the parent doesn't have a certain height so it takes what it needs also try to see how everything works together in css

```html
<div id="the whole thing" style="height:100vh; width:100%">

  <div id="toprow" style="position: relative; width:100%; height:150px; background-color:red;color:white">
    First row
  </div>

  <div id="secondrow" style="position: relative; width:100%; height: 300px;background-color:black;color:white">
    Second row
  </div>

  <div id="thirdrow" style="position: relative; width:100%; height:100%;background-color:blue;color:white">
    Third row
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this using `display: flex`.

You can try this:

```
<style>
    #thewholething{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #thirdrow{
        flex-grow: 1;
        align-self: stretch;
    }
</style>
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="thewholething" style="height:600px; width:100%">

    <div id="toprow" style="width:100%; height:150px; background-color:red;color:white">
        First row
    </div>

    <div id="secondrow" style="width:100%; height: 300px;background-color:black;color:white">
       Second row
    </div>

    <div id="thirdrow" style="width:100%; background-color:blue;color:white">
       Third row
    </div>
</div>
```

Try playing with the overall height of the parent DIV or the other DIVs and see the magic!

EDIT: You can try this without `align-self: stretch;` and it works too!

Comment: I'm trying that both with and without align-self: stretch; and I'm still getting a fourth white horizontal bar at the bottom. I really should learn flex properly if I'm going down this path.

Comment: Adding min-height: 100vh; to the  #thewholething container actually works with that approach.

Comment: I thought you wanted the 3rd div to consume the rest of the space of the parent. If so, the above solution is perfect. If you wanted the parent to consume the whole page then simply apply `height: 100vh` to the parent and it will work. You did not state that in the original problem hence I didn't recommend it.